# Stretched ImageViews in LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add 6 images as ImageButtons but these images are vertically stretched. See the image below:

[image]

As you can see in the above image all imagebutons are vertically stretched. I have placed them in drawable-xxxhdpi. The resolutions of each image is 512x512. I have also tried placing them in mipmap-xxxhdpi or xxhdpi but no difference. Here is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#DCDCDC"
tools:context="MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3.4">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_radio_channel_one"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_radio_channel_two"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_radio_channel_three"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3.4">

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_radio_channel_four"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_radio_channel_five"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/background_radio_channel_six"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any suggestions to make them look normal not stretched?
All these images are in PNG format.

Comment: fix sizes in image view: width=512 and height=512

Comment: try removing  android:scaleType="fitXY"

Answer (score 1):

Main **culprit** is `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Change it with

```
 android:scaleType="centerInside"  



scaleType="fitXY"` means image Stretch to its all corners
scaleType="centerInside"  means  place at center of parent
```

I suggest you to **Remove all weight  for all layout and Just Use only Linner Layout for all images**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#DCDCDC">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_channel_6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:scaleType="centerInside" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. First i tried replacing scaleType="centerInside" but it did nothing. Then i tried your code but all the images are now more vertically stretched. See the image 

https://s17.postimg.org/xnt9gbuhr/Screenshot_from_2016_12_01_19_38_45.png
Here are the icons that i used 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B32HX5u0sXk2Y212UWhFYjM5dnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Just try other options in scaleType attribute like center etc Still nothing happen that just remove that

Comment: I got this the reason is wight remove all android:weightSum="3" and  android:layout_weight="1" and     change   android:layout_width="0dp" to   android:layout_width="wrap_content"                                                                               


but if you do that screen is not divided into 3 part

Answer (score 0):

Try creating images supporting multiple screens using the below link which solves your problem...https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Answer (score 0):

Please try this updated code:

//Source code Sample.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;


public class Sample extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(Sample.this));
}
}
```

//ImageAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(170, 170));

        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {

    R.drawable.ic_radio_2, R.drawable.ic_radio_3,
    R.drawable.ic_radio_4, R.drawable.ic_radio_5,
    R.drawable.ic_radio_4, R.drawable.ic_radio_6,

};
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code but now the images are pinched. See the image https://s16.postimg.org/fqpo8bbmd/Screenshot_from_2016_12_01_19_47_11.png
Here are the icons that i use https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B32HX5u0sXk2Y212UWhFYjM5dnc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: yea....i downloaded your images and worked out .I tried with grid view programatically most probably i got a solution if you are ok with grid view i will post the answer after that you customize it based on your requirement

Comment: Yes please post the code that you tried. I don't care if it's gridview.
Thanks!

Comment: @LinuxHolic Could you please try this updated code and check it :)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Here is the code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_radio_5_art" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_channel_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/background_radio_channel_one" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_channel_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/background_radio_channel_two" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_channel_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/background_radio_channel_three" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_channel_4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/background_radio_channel_four" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_channel_5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/background_radio_channel_five" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/radio_channel_6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/background_radio_channel_six" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks to all those who helped me solve my problem :)